# Estoy descargando Sql server 2014 y al final de la descarga me aparece esto. Que tengo que hacer para solucionarlo?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como solucionar este error, necesito el programa para mis estudios y no importa que version descargue siempre me da ese error

Comment: Debes de revisar los permisos que tienes en la maquina donde lo haces, tu usuario de preferencia que sea administrador, tambien puede ser tu antivirus que esta bloqueando la descarga, te recomiendo tambien que lo trates de hacer con otro navegador y deshabilita el complemento de seguridad que la mayoria de antivirus instalan. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Asumo que estás instalando la versión Express. No es muy claro a qué te refieres con "no importa la versión que descargue".

Lo primero, descarga la versión más reciente del [sitio oficial](https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=42299).

Luego, como se indica en el sitio de descarga, debas [habilitar](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=120550) el framework .NET 3.5. El resumen de cómo habilitarlo es:

a) En tu escritorio, presiona la combinación de teclas `Win+R`.
b) Escribe en la ventana emergente `appwiz.cpl` y presiona Enter.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

c) En la ventana “Programas y Características” que aparece, haz clic en el enlace “Habilitar o deshabilitar características de Windows”.

d) Revisa si la opción “.NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)” esta disponible.

[image: características de windows]

e) Si es así, habilítalo y haz clic en OK / Aceptar.

f) Sigue luego las instrucciones en pantalla para la instalación y reinicia tu PC si te es solicitado.

Después es necesario instalar el framework .NET [versión 4](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=186791). Otras versiones del instalador lo descargar por sí mismas pero no recuerdo si este lo hace.

El instalador debería preguntarte qué versión de SQL Server usar. Puedes instalar Express con tools o Express con Advanced Services para que tengas disponible lo que necesitas.

Si nada de esto ayuda, intenta ejecutar el instalador como Adimnistrador. Clic derecho, Ejecutar como Administrador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta bro, el framework ya lo tenia habilitado y no me pidio reiniciar la pc, asi que voy a hacer los otros pasos que me diste.

PD: si, me referia a la express pense que la habia puesto